# QT Creator wont list any available Android Build SDKs

Tags: android, qt, sdk

When attempting to build and run an example project with QT Creator, it fails, saying:

```
Build failed
Warning: Android platform 'android--1' does not exist in SDK.
Building the android package failed!
```

All the solution I have found say to select the appropriate Android build SDK in the Build Android APK, however the dropdown for that option is grayed out:

[Empty Android build SDK dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6fbq.png)

When looking into this, the only solution I can find is people saying to make sure my JDK, SDK, and NDK paths were put into the `Tools > Options > Devices > Android` area, which I'd already done:

[SDK Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeeOR.png)

Haven't really been able to find what else could be causing the problem. Any ideas on where to go from here would be most appreciated.

Comment: I was facing the same problem last week. How did you install Android-SDK ? Through Android Studio Installation ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure that was the best way to go about it though.

Comment: Can you download and install "tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip" in https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html . Install this to the path where AndroidStudio created sdk.

Comment: Yup, looks like using an older version of tools got it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a problem with newest Android SDK Tools (25.3.0)

QT 5.8/QT Creator 4.2.1 uses old, now removed, executables from Android Tools.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html `SDK Tools, Revision 25.3.0 (March 2017)`:

> Obsolete/deprecated tools have been removed:
>
> - android

QT 5.8 will not work automatically with Android SDK Tools 25.3.0, and to make it work, you will need to modify files by hand:

- QT is unable to distinguish Android target versions and those need to be modified in `<project>.pro.user` file (QT must be closed while editing this file)
- Also from not documented changes, there is no longer `templates` folder available from Android SDK Tools. QT require them to be there to build, so you will need to copy them from AndroidStudio: `<path to AndroidStudio>\plugins\android\lib\templates` into `<path to Android SDK>\templates`

  > INFO: every update to SDK packages made through AndroidStudio will remove this folder, and you will need to copy it again

---

easiest solution would be to get older version of Android SDK Tools (and use them only for QT). I've managed to do so by modifying link from this site https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads to point to previous version:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

Comment: Went with the "easiest solution" and used that older version of the tools which immediately got it working. Thank you very much.

Comment: I had to place my `templates` folder in `<path to Android SDK>/tools/templates`

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with Qt 5.9 which I thought was suppose to be fixed. I'm just wondering if anyone has actually seen it work? or is this maybe an issue with 5.9 on windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

For linux users, the last version of SDK with UI:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip

This work automatically with Qt 5.8

Answer (score 1):

As was written by Patrizio Bekerle at [QTCREATORBUG-17852](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17852):

> For reference, this is the download link for the 25.2.5 sdk tools (for Linux) you currently need to build Android apps: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip
>   I found it on https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.co.at/p/android-sdk-tools.html
>   I was able to build again with this version...

It works for me on MacOS